# Windows server 2012R2 - Allow access website

Tags: php, port, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a problem with the configuration of my windows server 2012.
On this server, I have an apache tomcat service that runs on port 80 with IIS, so I can access, from an external ip to the website.

For a project, we also need to install a PHP service, so I installed apache and php, configured everything on port 8000, locally on the machine, from its external ip, I access the website well (90.90.90:90:8000 for example).

But when I try to access it from the outside, it doesn't work and I have this message :
" This site can't be reacher x.x.x.x took loog to respond - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

I added a rule in the firewall to allow connections to port 8000 but it doesn't change anything...

I don't know what else to configure, if someone has a solution!

Comment: port forwarding on your router ;-)

Comment: it's a server in the cloud (Azure), so I can't configure it, right?

Comment: You should be able to. Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: All right, I'll search the internet for ways to do it :/

Comment: Oh thx rly ! I thought I could do anything since the vm.